# Set second item margin-left according to first item width

Tags: html, css

I am using a widget. It generates an automatic html elements and I need to change every single css by myself.

As you see in snipped code, I tried something to show two `span` elements in one row. But if the first element contains long sentence, then second `span` doesn't get arranged by first one's width. How exactly can I set it?

```css
.remove-dot {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.display-list-item {
  display: list-item
}
```

```html
<span class="remove-dot display-list-item">test</span>
<span class="remove-dot display-list-item" style="margin-top: -17px; margin-left: 35px;">another span</span>
<br />
<span class="remove-dot display-list-item">second first span with long width</span>
<span class="remove-dot display-list-item" style="margin-top: -17px; margin-left: 35px;">another span</span>
```

Comment: what's the HTML markup of the closest parent element?

Comment: Actually the widget creates automatic <table> with <tbody>, <tr>, <td>,  so I am going to edit  <td> positions.

Comment: Not following you... so your `span`s are inside a `<td>`?

Comment: you can set `.display-list-item {
      display: inline-block;
    }`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes, `span`s are actually `<td>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete

```
.display-list-item {
  display: list-item
}
```

Or if you are not able the delete it you can change it like Banzay already mentioned in the comments.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Then your spans are in one row like here:

```css
.remove-dot {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<span class="remove-dot display-list-item">test</span>
<span class="remove-dot display-list-item" style="margin-top: -17px; margin-left: 35px;">another span</span>
<br />
<span class="remove-dot display-list-item">second first span with long width</span>
<span class="remove-dot display-list-item" style="margin-top: -17px; margin-left: 35px;">another span</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking like this??

```css
   

 div{
        float:left;
    }
    .remove-dot {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
```

```html
  

 <div>
    <span class="remove-dot display-list-item">test1</span></br>
<span class="remove-dot display-list-item">second first span with long width</span>
   </div> 
<div>
    <span class="remove-dot display-list-item" style="margin-top: -17px; margin-left: 35px;">test2</span></br>
    <span class="remove-dot display-list-item" style="margin-top: -17px; margin-left: 35px;">another span</span>
</div>
```